# How to know if there is an action on the DB in Java?

Tags: java

I have two applications A and B and I need to modify data in B that comes through a DB from A (check if there is a new record in a specific table).
I have put an infinite loop on B, however I think that is not the best solution.

```
int i = 0;

    for(;;)
    {
        for(i = 0; i <= 600000;)
        {
            i++;    
        }
        //Check if there is a new record in a table from app A.

        String raw_xml = B.checkDB();
        //if there is a new record in a table from app do the
        // function doPingTest ()
        if (raw_xml!= null)
        {
            new TestB().doPingTest(raw_xml);
        }

        i = 0;
    }
```

Comment: What is your requirement? What you tried earlier? What was the output? Please update the question, so that will be easy to understand and answer to that accordingly.

Comment: This sounds perhaps like a job for Message Queuing (MQ). The name RabbitMQ leaps to mind, but there are many others as well.  Just Google "message queue software" and go from there.

Comment: OK, I will Google "message queue software". Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After doing some tests with other alternatives, this is the best solution:

```
for(;;)
{
  while(true)
  {
    //sleep one minute
    Thread.sleep(60 * 1000);
    //Check if there is a new record in the DB
    String raw_xml = B.checkDB();
        if (raw_xml!= null)
        {
            new TestB().doPingTest(raw_xml);
        }
  }         
}
```